# fork() - Can you explain this output

Tags: process, fork

I'm stuck understanding the output of this program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
void fork1()
{
 printf("\n %d L0", getpid());
 fork();
 printf("\n %d L1", getpid());
 fork();
 printf("\n %d Bye", getpid());
}

int main()
{
fork1();
return 0;
}
```

**Output**

2625 L0

2625 L0

2625 L1

2625 Bye 2626 L1

2626 Bye 2625 L1

2627 Bye 2626 L1

2628 Bye

Comment: Two issues: 1) "printf()" is buffered.  The characters don't display immediately; they display only when the OS decides to flush it.  2) Furthermore, the OS can (and probably will) swap back and forth between your different processes in the *middle* of an I/O write.  These two issues should explain the "interleaving" you're seeing in the output.

Answer (score 0):

There are three key points:

1. fork() would copy the buffer of parent-process
2. printf is working on buffer
3. printf would flush the buffer while it comes with "\n", EOF, etc

So, if you change the printf to printf("XXXX\n"), things would become normal